# NameError (uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper):

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Whatever error i get in my app i couldnt see the error in my logs am getting the below 
message for all the errors am facing so i couldnt solve my error, could anyone help me out of this.??

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 729ms

NameError (uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper):


Rendered /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (7.7ms)
```

Comment: ExceptionWrapper requires rails 3.2 but this dependency isn't specified in the gemspec

Comment: now i dont want exception wrapper.. how could i remove this??

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `meta_request` gem installed?
I also had such error and got rid of it by removing the `meta_request` gem.